# Unable to download private videos in yt-dlp

Tags: yt-dlp, .netrc

I have created .netrc then supplied the credentials as as advised in the format

`machine youtube login myawesomelogin password verycomplicatepass`

Is there something I need to do again?

In downloading I typed:
`yt-dlp --netrc url`

Comment: Do you get any errors or messages after executing the command?

Comment: Yes I get errors that :

Private video. Sign in if you've been granted access to this video

Comment: Probably the session or cookies are not recognized somehow. Can you post the `--verbose` log? - consider also check the [open issues on github](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen) as well.

Comment: Do you have your .netrc in ~, if not you need to specify `--netrc-location PATH` (Defaults to ~/.netrc)